# Getting error message while opening a pdf document

Tags: pdf, locked

I'm getting the below error message while opening a pdf file. Please advise wht action need to be taken to resolve this.

**Word found locked fields during the update. Word can't update locked fields.**

Comment: *"opening a pdf file"* - opening in what program?

Comment: Adobe reader or via Microsoft edge browser

Comment: Are you sure? It does not make sense for Adobe Reader to show an error message "Word found locked fields during the update. Word can't update locked fields."

Comment: Usually, what might be the reason for this kind of error?

Comment: First of all, that error message sounds like a program called "Word" is used here, not Acrobat or Edge. And it looks like that "Word" program does not fully support the pdf format.

Comment: Alternatively there might be some Javascript program in the pdf calling itself "Word" which does not get along with the current state of the pdf.

Comment: Googling around seems to indicate that that error message is from MS Word.